# LIMS-technical standards indexing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have technical standards that look like this [image]

How would you upload it in the database without losing the natural indexing of this procedure using these fields:

- point
- name
- description
  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can split by first:

- paragraph -> point, name, description

then split these

- first space -> **point** + name, description

then split the second part

- first dot -> **name** + **description**